# How do I get data from two tables in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `user_info` and `topics` table like this:

user_info table with columns:

```
id, username, userImage, token, role
```

topics table with columns:

```
id, topicId, title, details, dayPosted, username, userImage
```

On user login, I would like to get information from `topics` table and `role` from `user_role` table.

For now I am getting the data like this, but this doesn't include role information.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/get_data_on_login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity get_data_on_login(@RequestParam(value="username") String username) throws Exception {
        List<TopicBean> topicBean = topicService.findAllTopics();
        return new ResponseEntity(topicBean, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

How do I user role as well from `user_role` table along with above data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with something like:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/get_data_on_login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get_data_on_login(
       @RequestParam(value="username") String userName) throws Exception {
  List<TopicBean> topics = topicService.findAllTopics( userName );
  List<UserRoleBean> roles = roleService.findAllRoles( userName );
  return new ResponseEntity( new LoginData( topics, roles ), HttpStatus.OK );
}
```

Your `LoginData` class would be:

```
public class LoginData {
   private final List<TopicBean> topics;
   private final List<UserRoleBean> roles;

   public LoginData(List<TopicBean> topics, List<UserRoleBean> roles) {
     this.topics = topics;
     this.roles = roles;
   }

   public List<TopicBean> getTopics() { return topics; }
   public List<UserRoleBean> getRoles() { return roles; }   }
}
```

You would get a JSON response that looked like:

```
{ "topics": [{topic1},{topic2}], "roles": [{role1},{role2}] }
```

Comment: I get error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userInfoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllRoles found for type UserInfo!`

Comment: I have `@Column(name = "role")
    private String role = "ROLE_USER";` inside `UserInfo` entity class

Comment: Inside DB table, I have column as `role`. Shall I change it `roles`?

Comment: Fixed it like this:   `@RequestMapping(path = "/get_data_on_login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity get_data_on_login(@RequestParam(value="username") String username) throws Exception {
        List<TopicBean> topics = topicService.findAllTopics();
        UserInfo role = userInfoService.findRoleByUsername(username);
        return new ResponseEntity(new LoginDataBean( topics, role.getRole(), role.getUserImage()),  HttpStatus.OK);
    }`

Comment: Right, you'd need to adopt my example code to your specific use case, but it seems you figured that out.   Good luck.